# Has anybody made self updating mutable table view based on a RACSignal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa, racsignal

Now that there's a [full support for KVO](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/212), has anybody made a mutable table view that takes a RACSignal as its dataSource? Ideally something that doesn't require any configuration.

```
RACSignal *commentsSignal;
UITableView *table = [UITableView new];
table.dataSourceSignal = commentsSignal;
[self.view addSubview:table];
// No more basic config
```

Comment: Content of the table view is not just a collection of objects, but there is much more: heights, sections, titles, custom cell, … So you will have to do much more to fully configure the table view.

Comment: Af you are asking only for reloading, insertions, deletions and moving of cells, then this is what I usually do, but again: every table is so different, that I didn't find universal case for this.

Comment: Sorry, this question was about data and collection observers, not appearance. Using ReactiveCocoa, Nimbus, and something like [CueTableReloader](https://github.com/Cue/CueTableReloader), you could make a table view that automatically rearranges itself when you change a collection of models, all in about 4 lines of code.

Comment: (Off topic: I don't know what do you mean.)

Comment: I will try to put together universal code for managing data source automatically using RAC. May be usefull for many people.

Answer (score 2):

ReactiveCocoa 3.0 (currently in development) adds a category on UITableView that does just that.

I haven't updated it in a couple weeks, but I made an early podspec for it: https://gist.github.com/adlai-holler/ae321c3398d7db9a55c0

Comment: Can't find it anymore

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have created a 'binding helper' that binds a table view to a signal:

http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2014/05/11/reactivecocoa-tableview-binding.html

You can use it to bind a signal to table view where the cell is defined in a nib, as shown below:

```
// create a cell template
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CETweetTableViewCell" bundle:nil];

// bind the ViewModels 'searchResults' property to a table view
[CETableViewBindingHelper bindingHelperForTableView:self.searchResultsTable
                        sourceSignal:RACObserve(self.viewModel, searchResults)
                        templateCell:nib];
```

In the above example the table view is bond to an `NSArray` property on a view model via `RACObserve(self.viewModel, searchResults)`, however any `RACSignal` that emits an array will bind just fine.

Comment: I was looking for something that fully supports mutable data, so I haven't upvoted your answer. I also declined Holler's answer because I can't find the category he's talking about and RC 3.0 is not released yet.

Comment: no problem - you mention you are looking for something that "fully supports mutable data". I'm just wondering if you could expand on that a little? What specific scenario do you want to support?

Comment: Both addition and removal from the source array should cause appropriate table cell animations. Mixed bulk addition/removal should also call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` on the table.

Comment: @Michael, I have created a binding helper similar to Colin's, but it supports appropriate table cell animations. [HFTableCollectionBindingHelper](https://github.com/haifengkao/HFTableCollectionBindingHelper)

Comment: I have rename the project to [HFViewBinding](https://github.com/haifengkao/HFViewBinding). Shorter name is easier to type.